# Making the $y$-axis ticks on a plot be a function of a parameter

Tags: plotting

Sorry if the title is wordy. Basically, what I am asking would probably be easier if I just use an example.

Say I wanted to plot $f(x) = A\sin(x)$ and have the graph come up showing the sine function with the ticks on the $y$-axis being half-integer multiples of $A$. What I have been doing for my homework assignments is just plotting $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and then turning off the ticks and manually adding my own ticks. It would be really cool if *Mathematica* could do this for me.

Comment: I think what you ended up doing is perhaps the best way... it isn't all that complicated either.

Comment: What do you mean by manually?  Are you using a custom tick specification as in this documentation example?: `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Ticks -> {{{Pi, 180 \[Degree], {0, .5}, Red}, {2 Pi, 360 \[Degree], {.5, 0}, 
     Thick}, {3 Pi, 540 \[Degree], {0, .5}, Directive[Red, Dashed]}}, {-1, 1}}]`

Answer (score 1):

See [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html#58219888) in the documentation:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{y, Row[{y, " A"}]}, {y, -1, 1, 1/2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unless you meant A to be a numeric value:

```
With[{A = Sqrt[2]},
 Plot[A Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[-1, 1, 1/2] A}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(OK, `A = Sqrt[2]` is a bit random. :)